# Is asynchronous methods call strategy via delegate callback the right way?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

When I want to make a method to be accessible synchronously and asynchronously and then I wrap it inside of a `Thread` and return the result via a delegate callback.

Is this is a good strategy or is it a really bad way of programming?

```
public delegate void FooDelegate(bool foo);

public bool FooMethod()
{
    //snychron operation
    return true;
}

public void FooMethodAsync(FooDelegate fooDelegate)
{
    ThreadStart fooThreadStart = () =>
    {
        fooDelegate?.Invoke(FooMethod());
    };
    Thread fooThreadStartThread = new Thread(fooThreadStart) { IsBackground = true };
    fooThreadStartThread.Start();            
}
```

call the methods:

```
FooClass fooClass = new FooClass();

//Call Synchron
var fooResult = fooClass.Disconnect();

//Call with Callback async
fooClass.DisconnectAsync(ResultCallback);


private static void ResultCallback(bool foo)
{

}
```

#### Edit

Here is a good reading:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async (thanks *pstrjds*)
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957 (**Task-based Asynchronous Pattern**)

Comment: And how do you get the result (`true`) from your `FooMethodAsync`?

Comment: That's what `BeginInvoke` is for.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) on `async` and `await`. They will help you.

Comment: @Evk added an example how to call.

Comment: @pstrjds thanks for your link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not a good pattern.  You should only expose both synchronous and asynchronous methods for an operation when the asynchronous implementation is *inherently* asynchronous in nature (and the synchronous implementation is inherently synchronous in nature), rather than simply a call to the synchronous implementation in a new thread, or a thread pool thread.  (An exception can sometimes be made for situations where an object needs to implement an interface providing a synchronous and asynchronous implementation, even if only one makes sense.)  If the caller wants to perform the synchronous operation asynchronously in a new thread, or a thread pool thread, they can easily do so themselves, in the situations where it's necessary.  This also more effectively communicates what's going on.  If a caller sees an asynchronous method they're going to assume that that operation is *inherently* asynchronous, which would be a false assumption in your case.

Additionally, it's not considered a good practice anymore to use a callback based model.  Instead, the Task based model is used, in which an asynchronous method returns a `Task`, which can itself be used to add a continuation to be run when the asynchronous operation finishes, along with providing numerous other features.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Then I'll read about the `TAP`. When do you use callbacks nowadays?

Comment: @DominicJonas When dealing with old APIs that were written before Tasks came out, or that were written by a mean person who didn't use the preferable model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FooMethodAsync(FooDelegate fooDelegate)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        var result = FooMethod();
        fooDelegate(result);
    });
}
```

This method is unstable for exceptions. `Task.Run` will end immediately but if exceptions will be raised inside `FooMethod` or `fooDelegate`, your application will be aborted. It's no so good but you can ignore these exceptions:

```
public void FooMethodAsync(FooDelegate fooDelegate)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        try
        {
            var result = FooMethod();
            fooDelegate(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Who cares?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not the way. You should use the `Task` and `Task<T>` classes as return type, and use Task.Run() in your method to invoke operations in thread pool threads, this is called "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern".

```
internal Task<Bitmap> RenderAsync(
                 ImageData data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       return Task.Run(() =>
       {
           var bmp = new Bitmap(data.Width, data.Height);
           for(int y=0; y<data.Height; y++)
           {
               cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               for(int x=0; x<data.Width; x++)
               {
                   // render pixel [x,y] into bmp
               }
           }
           return bmp;
       }, cancellationToken);
   }
```

Also, your method must have the async keyword in order to be called from async code.

More here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Also, your method must have the async keyword in order to be called from async code" < how's that?